# Nodemailer send an anonymous email

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer

I'm using [NodeMailer](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer). It is working well but I want to send an anonymous email (with a fake name and email adress) it doesn't as it should be. Here is my code :

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                host: 'smtp.gmail.com', 
                port: 587,
                secure: false,
                auth: {
                   user: 'myrealAdress@gmail.com', 
                   pass: 'mypass' 
                }
            });
            var textMail = emailContent
            fs.readFile("./"+myCSV.name+".csv", function (err, data) {
                    transporter.sendMail({       
                        from: 'JourneyBuilder <noreply.journeybuilder@gmail.com>',
                        to: userToSendMail,
                        subject: subjectMail,
                        text: textMail,
                        attachments: [{'filename': myCSV.name+'.csv', 'content': data}]
            }), function(err, success) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("ERROR SEND : "+err);
                    }
            }
});
```

When I send this I receive the email well, the name is '**Journey Builder**' but the email is still mine `(the transporter's one: myrealAdress@gmail.com)` where it should be `'noreply.journeybuilder@gmail.com'`. Thanks to help me if you have any idea on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know (by the docs) it's not possible to hide your Email completly when sending a mail via `nodemailer`. you can either use a own mailserver or just set the replyaddress to the noreply address like this:

```
transporter.sendMail({       
  from: 'JourneyBuilder <noreply.journeybuilder@gmail.com>',
  replyTo: 'noreply.journeybuilder@gmail.com'
  ...
```

means people would reply to this address and not to the one you sent the mail with

Comment: Ok thanks ! Is there a package like NodeMailer able to do this or not ?

Comment: @Pierre-AdrienDelisle it's not `nodemailer` that doesn't support that, it's gmail. I'm not sure if you can handle it with google apps or if there's a workarround, but gmail has a pretty nice api (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) maybe you find the solution inside there. I couldnt find it and searched quite a while when i set up my own webpage with mailserver... and found no forum entries about it so i think its not possible... ;(

Comment: @Pierre-AdrienDelisle if it's really that important to fake the 'from' field consider using SES (aws-ses), there it's possible and not even that hard to implement  http://nodemailer.com/transports/ses/